# Wi-Fi Network Device Not Ready (firmware missing)

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, internet, networksetup

I have installed Debian 9 Stretch on my PC. I cannot connect to the Wi-Fi because it says that a firmware is missing. I didn't have this problem when I have Lubuntu installed.

It was looking for brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw during installation and I skipped this part.

Comment: Provide us some details about you network card. For example: `sudo lshw -class network`

Comment: Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: I have found this on the web and I am not sure what exactly I should do. https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-brcm80211

Comment: It was looking for brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw during installation and I skipped this part.

Answer (score 2):

You've correctly identified the required `firmware-brcm80211` package. But Debian is stricter about the principles of free software than Ubuntu, and so the firmware is in the "non-free" section of the Debian package repository. This section may not be enabled on your system by default, unless you had the foresight to specifically choose it during installation.

In `/etc/apt/sources.list`, there will be one or more lines like this:

deb  stretch

If that file is empty, there can be other repository configuration files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

Typically, the `<repository section keywords>` might include just `main` by default. You'll want to change it to at least `main non-free`.

After that, you should run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install firmware-brcm80211`. Then either unload+reload the kernel module of your Wi-Fi interface, or simply reboot.

Comment: I gave up. I just reinstalled Lubuntu. Debian is just not for me. Lubuntu works out of the box without getting any problems. But thanks for the help. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot connect to the Wi-Fi because it says that a firmware is missing. I didn't have this problem when I have Lubuntu installed.

Why?

The BCMxxx wifi card use a `non-free` firmware and the official debian image do not include the `non-free` software , using the official image you can load the missing firmware from a formatted fat32 USB device after extraction the firmware from [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware) (exactly [firmware-brcm80211](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-brcm80211))

You have skipped this steps during the system install , you can get the wifi working following the  answer of [telecoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) through the `firmware-brcm80211` package or following the [debian docs](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) by installing the `broadcom-sta-dkms` then loading the non-free module `wl`.

You don't have a problem using  Lubuntu because it include the `non-free` firmware.

A non official debian image including the non-free software is available to get the wifi working during the system install.

[Unofficial non-free images including firmware packages](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/)

Comment: I downloaded the Debian Stretch with non-official firmware from here and still it doesn't work. https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/9.4.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-cd/